# How to intercept SAML response in a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, saml, intercept

I have a use case where I would like to get the SAML Response(assertion) from IdP by intercepting (in the web browser) the javascript redirect (HTTP POST binding)to SP. The SAML response that's captured will then be sent to the SP programatically.

I have already looked at [Android bug - cannot access request POST headers](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155250)

Comment: Are you talking about a usual browser or about a webview inside an Android app?

Comment: web view inside an android app.

Comment: Ok, important to know, because if you spoke about a usual browser communication there'd be some handy browser extensions. Anyways, that's not your case. So you described what you wanna do but not what's your actual problem is. What have you tried so far (can you show a code snippet?) and do you e.g. get an exception or something like that?